# Sharing AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration for git deployment to AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk but I need to have other team members deploy as well.
We are using AWS eb CLI, which is very handy. But, it adds all generated configuration directory to .gitignore, removing the directory from .gitignore isn't a good idea.

Any ideas or tools that would allow me to share the configuration (I already shared the key) with team members so they can deploy as well?

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: Nope @NikMartin, no luck at all.

Comment: I answered you below, stating that it is ok to remove .elasticbeanstalk from .gitignore, as long as you aware of potential hangups, which I also described.

Comment: @owahab, were you able to figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: @NiravGandhi nope. Stopped using Elasticbeansalk altogether :)

Answer (score 2):

It technically is OK for you to check in .elasticbeanstalk, but let me give you a few caveats: You and your team need to be very very specific on the order of operations, or you will get your self in a bad situation. For example: ApplicationVersionName= is the last version that was deployed, so the user deploying needs to deploy to AWS, THEN commit to the remote. Everyone needs to the PULL from the remote before doing anything else. You also need all of your config files in a common place, because the config file by default references files in your user directory, like credential files.Those need to move up to a common folder.  There's probably more downside than upside to having ore than one deployment person though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, the Beanstalk Maven Plugin is a good choice to keep the configurations into your pom. Likely it will solve your sharing problem.

[Check out the documentation](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/index.html).

Regarding security, credentials are kept on *~/.m2/settings.xml* and protected by [Maven server password](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) encryption mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

May be make sense to describe your beanstalk environments with help of cloudformation templates?